# How to set a value in a specific byte?

Tags: c++, c, shared-memory

I am working with MapViewOfFile() and SharedMemory. I am able to read memory content byte by byte! Now I am wondering, how to set new hex values to a specific byte? Due to my code I was hoping that in my second console.log the hex value 0xffc8 is in cell 83. Unfortunately that is not the case.

```
// main method 
FILE * pBuf = (FILE*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
...
int d;
BYTE dbgByte;
for(d = 0; d < 86; d++){ 
    dbgByte = *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d));
    printf("DEBUG byte %i hexvalue %hhx \n", d, (char) dbgByte); 
    printf("DEBUG byte %i int %i \n", d, (int) dbgByte); 
}
// DEBUG - END
for(d = 0; d < 86; d++){ 
    if (d == 83){ // 0xffc8 = 200
    BYTE writeByte1;
    writeByte1 = *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d));
    writeByte1 = 0xffc8;
    }
}
// DEBUG 2 - START
for(d = 0; d < 86; d++){ 
    dbgByte = *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d));
    printf("DEBUG byte %i hexvalue %hhx \n", d, (char) dbgByte); 
    printf("DEBUG byte %i int %i \n", d, (int) dbgByte); 
}
// DEBUG - END
...
```

UPDATE: tried Bill's adivce - unfortunately this didn't work as well:

```
if (d == 84){ // 0x42 = 66
    *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d)) = 0x42;
}
```

UPDATE-2: tried Captain Oblivious advice - unfortunately the writing-procedure did not work. I am not able see the hex value 42 in my debug-3 logging statement.

```
for(d = 0; d < 86; d++){ 
    byte = pBuf[d];
    printf("DEBUG-1 ");
    printf("hex:  %hhx; ", byte);
    printf("char:  %c; ", (char) byte);
    printf("dec: %i; ", (int) byte);
    printf(" byte %i; ", d);
    printf("\n");
    if (d == 84){ // 0x42 = 66
        pBuf[d] = 0x42;
        printf("DEBUG-3 ");
        printf("hex:  %hhx; ", byte);
        printf("char:  %c; ", (char) byte);
        printf("dec: %i; ", (int) byte);
        printf(" byte %i; ", d);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning to fit `0xffc8` in a single byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify reading and writing greatly by declaring `pBuf` as `std::uint8_t*`, `unsigned char*` or `BYTE*` instead of `FILE*`.

```
std::uint8_t* pBuf = static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(
    MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE));
```

This would allow you to manipulate the data as an array. You would could then change the way you read a byte from the following

```
var = *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d));
```

to

```
var = pBuf[d];
```

This also makes changing the value just as easy.

```
pBuf[d] = var;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice captain - anyway, I was not able to set the new value yet.

Comment: Thanks Captain, now it works. I looked at the wrong variable :-)

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
writeByte1 = *((PBYTE) pBuf + (d));
writeByte1 = 0xffc8;
```

copies the value from `pBuf` into local variabl `writeByte1`, and then changes the local variable to be something else.

Try writing to the buffer instead:

```
*((PBYTE) pBuf + (d)) = 0xff;
*((PBYTE) pBuf + (d+1)) = 0xc8;
```

Response to edit:

The code to modify memory works, as you can see here: https://ideone.com/EKsvmU
The problem may be with how you are working with `MapViewOfFile`. For instance, `MapViewOfFile()` does not return a `FILE*`.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I tried your example (see my edited post) - unfortunately no success!

Comment: So you can ask better questions, you should know that saying "no success" is not helpful. Say what you saw, and what you expected to see.

Comment: Ah okay, I expected to see my newly set value ('42 (hex)') and I saw the old one, '00'.

Comment: @Jochen: You may be handling MapViewOfFile incorrectly then. It doesn't return a `FILE*`.

Comment: Also, the "volatile" keyword exists for a reason.. ;-)